# how to enable linux support users for a certain no of hrs using php

Tags: php, linux

I want to enable linux support user for 8 hours and then lock his login automatically.

Front end is built using PHP and below is what I have used ..

```
// Enabling Support
shell_exec("sudo passwd -u support");
// Time to Expire
$date = date("h:i:s A", strtotime('+8 hours'));
$timeat = substr($date,0,2).substr($date,9,11);
// Cron setup using 'at' command 
shell_exec("sudo at ".$timeat." -f /path/to/cron/disablesupport.php");
```

disablesupport.php has the below code.

```
//Locking Support
shell_exec("passwd -l support");
```

This didn't work. Please fix and help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Revise the PHP.ini file for custom time configuration.

For Ubuntu, the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file should be revised.

Change the line: `session.gc_maxlifetime=28800`

(28800 seconds = 8 hours)

Comment: why should the php.ini be changed? the command itself is not working from php.

Comment: I am recommending a different way to manage this.  To "login" check the user's credentials, and if they are okay, create a session cookie.   Then the cookie will default to lasting 8 hours.  If the cookie is expired, it will ask for the credentials again.

Comment: it is not about the application login for the support user ... but it is about the login to linux box